# Django REST Framework Multiple OR'd Custom Permissions' Message Not Shown

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, permissions

I'm trying to write a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` where the permission classes are set as follows:

```
permission_classes = (IsUserCat | CanDogsRetrieveObject,)
```

`permissions.py`:

```
class IsUserCat(IsAuthenticated):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return super().has_object_permission(request, view, obj) and request.user.species == SPECIES_CAT

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return super().has_permission(request, view) and request.user.species == SPECIES_CAT


class IsUserDog(IsAuthenticated):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return super().has_object_permission(request, view, obj) and request.user.species == SPECIES_DOG

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return super().has_permission(request, view) and request.user.species == SPECIES_DOG


class CanDogsRetrieveObject(IsUserDog):
    message = "Some custom message."

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return super().has_permission(request, view)

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return super().has_object_permission(request, view, obj) and obj.expiry_date >= timezone.now().date()
```

So basically, the first permission class checks if the user is a cat, if so, the user can retrieve the object; if not, the second permission class checks if the user is a dog and if the object in question is expired. If it's expired, a custom error message must be displayed, but it doesn't. If I don't `OR` them, and instead just use `CanDogsRetrieveObject` then the issue gets resolved. Why is this the case?

Comment: You didn't set the `message` attribute on any of the classes.

Comment: Hi, @BaranUgur. Could you please provide your view and models ?

Comment: @heemayl I tried that; unfortunately, it doesn't work.